# Realsense D435i distortion

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ! I'm an Embedded Systems student and I need your help :) !

- First my distribution is Melodic and I'm on Jetson Xavier NX (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I use an Intel Realsense D435i to make 3D SLAM in RTAB-Map.
- Now my problem ! I use IMU and visual odemetry fusing in ukf (robot_localization package). The results looks likes good, but I can watching distortion in max range cloud map.

I want to fixe that problem and for that I want to remove or delete the max range datas to just take the datas without distortion. To do that I think there are 2 soltutions :

- First modify the Realsense code. I currently try that but I'm stuck beacause I don't find this parameter.
- Make a code can take datas from /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw topic, filter the max range datas and publish it on new topic and remap RTAB-Map (arg name="depth_topic") by the new topic.

THX for help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373546/realsense-d435i-distortion/) by [Evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/54952/evan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

D435i depth accuracy is not very good over ~3.5 meters. Instead of filtering the depth images, you can adjust set rtabmap parameter `Grid/RangeMax` to 3.5 for example.

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
  ...
  <param name="Grid/RangeMax" value="3.5"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/54952/evan/) on 2021-03-09**:
Hi, thank you for your answer !

I want to test that but in rtabmap.launch file, there are not param name "Grid/RangeMax". I'm using the **opensource_tracking.launch** file in realsense2_camera package, I just remove linear_accel_cov and unite_imu_method and I add the gyro and accel "true". Now in  I add   but when I'm roslaunch I have an error because there are not Grid/RangeMax in the rtabmap_ros.launch .

I'm searching for find that param or my mistakes.

**Comment by [Evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/54952/evan/) on 2021-03-10**:
Hi matlabbe,

I find the solutions to my problem, in my case I use RTAB-Map to make 3D SLAM and i have changed `cloud_max_depth` and `cloud_min_depth` values to [3 ; 0.3] (Intel Realsense D435i settings). I think `Grid/RangeMax` is for 2D occupancy grid but i'm not sure.

Now I have an other question, it's the `cloud_decimation` setting. I don't understand what is it :) .

RTAB-Map it's a really good package, you make good job ! Thank you for your help !!!

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2021-03-11**:
`cloud_max_depth` and `cloud_min_depth` are remapped to `Grid/RangeMax` and `Grid/RangeMin` parameters : https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/8d053bc43f0045378406f0aa0c694244337e4b42/src/MapsManager.cpp#L285-L286

`cloud_decimation` is remapped to `Grid/DepthDecimation`, which is the decimation of the depth image before creating point cloud.

If you are using rtabmap.launch, you can feed the RTAB-Map's parameters (those shown with rtabmap --params) by doing:
`roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch args:="--delete_db_on_start --Grid/RangeMax 3 --Grid/RangeMin 0.3 --Grid/DepthDecimation 4"`